# Can't connect to some web hosting FTPs after installing DD-WRT on my router

Tags: networking, router, ftp, dd-wrt

I have recently installed DD-WRT on my D-Link DIR-615 router. Everything seems fine but I cannot connect to *some* FTP servers (web hosting) anymore. Any ideas what can cause this issue?

CuteFTP is telling me that it dies (timeout) at "Connecting FTP data socket" but on some FTPs it just load the root dir and nothing else after, displaying the previous mentioned error.

What I've tried:

- FTP Passive Mode on or off
- disabling the SPI Firewall from DD-WRT